# Determine maximum likelihood estimators in terms of "quantized" data

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be a random sample from a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$. Let $L, U$ be real numbers such that $L < U$.
Let $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ be "quantized" versions of $X_1, \cdots, X_n$, defined as
$$ Y_i = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & X_i < L \\
0 & L \leq X_i \leq U \\
1 & X_i > U
\end{array}
\right.
$$

How can we determine the maximum likelihood estimators for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ based on $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ (instead of $X_1, \cdots, X_n$).

I don't really know how to start this question. I was thinking that the invariance principle for the maximum likelihood estimator can be somehow use here, and I am not sure to what function to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on $\hat{\mu}=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$

the rv $Y_i$ is $\pm1$ if the corresponding $X_i$ is higher than an Upper value or smaller than a Lower value of X. (zero does not affect the calculation)

So I think that is enough to express Y in function of X, say

$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i>U\}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{\{X_i<L\}}\Bigg]$$

thus the numerator will be a sum of 1,1,1,-1,-1....accordingly

Similar brainstorming for the other estimator